# TLA+: Temporal properties not being checked

Tags: tla+

I've got this toy example and for some reason none of the temporal properties are never asserted. Even ridiculous ones like `[](h = 123456)` don't fail TLC. What am I not understanding?

**intro.tla**

```
----------------------------------------------------- MODULE intro -----------------------------------------------------

EXTENDS Naturals

VARIABLE h

Init == h \in 1..12

Invariants == h \in 1..12

Next == h' = (h%12) + 1

Spec ==
 /\ Init
 /\ [][Next]_h
 \* None of these cause the model checker to fail
 /\ (\A i \in 1..15 : []<>(h = i))
 /\ []<>(h = 123456)
 /\ [](h = 123456)
 /\ <>(h = 123456)
 /\ [](FALSE)

THEOREM Spec => []Invariants

=======================================================================================================================
```

**intro.cfg**

```
SPECIFICATION Spec
INVARIANTS Invariants
```

**tlc intro**

```
TLC2 Version 2.13 of 18 July 2018 (rev: bfdbe00)
Running breadth-first search Model-Checking with seed -1431825986697619670 with 8 workers on 8 cores with 7131MB heap and 64MB offheap memory (Linux 5.0.0-arch1-1-ARCH amd64, Oracle Corporation 1.8.0_202 x86_64).
Parsing file /home/golly/projects/private/talks-wip/tla/intro.tla
Parsing file /tmp/Naturals.tla
Semantic processing of module Naturals
Semantic processing of module intro
Starting... (2019-03-11 12:20:09)
Computing initial states...
Computed 2 initial states...
Computed 4 initial states...
Computed 8 initial states...
Finished computing initial states: 12 distinct states generated.
Model checking completed. No error has been found.
  Estimates of the probability that TLC did not check all reachable states
  because two distinct states had the same fingerprint:
  calculated (optimistic):  val = 7.8E-18
  based on the actual fingerprints:  val = 1.6E-18
24 states generated, 12 distinct states found, 0 states left on queue.
The depth of the complete state graph search is 0.
The average outdegree of the complete state graph is 0 (minimum is 0, the maximum 0 and the 95th percentile is 0).
Finished in 00s at (2019-03-11 12:20:09)
```

Comment: Your spec contains `[](FALSE)` -- since `[](FALSE) => FALSE` and `FALSE => A` for any `A`, there can't be a countermodel.

Answer (score 0):

Behavior specs consist of an initial state (`Init`) and a next-state formula (`[][Next]_h`). I believe what's happening here is that the IDE or TLC are seeing those two and ignoring the rest. As it probably should: those additional clauses don't make the behavior violate your properties: they simply say that there are fewer initial states and actions than you thought. If you want to make them *properties* of your spec,  add those clauses to `Properties` in the Toolbox.